# Who is the most pervasive character in the Star Trek 'verse to cross all series?

Tags: star-trek

Cross all series means, has any (major or minor) character appeared in all of:

- The Original Series
- The Animated Series
- The Next Generation
- Deep Space Nine
- Voyager
- Enterprise
- Discovery
- The TOS era films
- The TNG era films (including Generations)
- The Reboot era films

Appearances primarily, but if they are mentioned I would accept that too.

Comment: This wording courtesy @JohnP.

Comment: And I still posit likely candidates are: Kirk, Spock, Sarek, Cochrane, Kahless

Comment: Oh, sure, lay it all on me. :p

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_crossovers

Comment: Adding "mentioned prominently" makes this overly broad. What constitutes a mention?

Comment: @Valorum - I had said in the comments that it should affect the plot somehow, but I left it up to the OP to determine that.

Comment: @Valorum:   Mentioned means mentioned.   I would accept that ***GEORDI:*** *"This is going to be like being there to watch Chuck Yeager break the sound barrier, or Zephram Cochrane engage the first warp drive. "* ("New Ground")  is a prominent enough mention.   If you have a corner case that actually matters, then ask about it.

Comment: @ThePopMachine  - This would be better (and answerable) if you restricted it to simple appearances

Comment: Does pervasive mean they were in more episodes/movies than anyone else or that they had at least one appearance in more episodes/movies than the others? For example: Worf was probably in more episodes than any other character because he was a main character on 2 series and all TNG era movies but Riker appeared on TNG, VOY and ENT as well as all the TNG era movies but only had single appearances outsite of TNG

Comment: Are the movies counted separately, or as era-based buckets?

Comment: (please edit the question so it can be re-opened I've already put a lot of thought into answering this)

Comment: Does appearing in *Trials and Tribbleations* count as TOS?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I've made a small edit to try to make this more objectively answerable, and reopened it.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFisha, yes,  they count as buckets.

Comment: @Valorum, it would not be **better**.  Stop insisting it would.   It would be a **different question**, is all it would be.

Comment: @Valorum : An accepted answer with (at this time) 27 upvotes suggests that this question is answerable.

Comment: @Praxis  - I would contend that this is an instance where a poorly scoped question has generated a poorly scoped answer. Both look sufficiently *alike* good questions/answers to fool the casual viewer.

Comment: @Valorum:   What do you even think poorly scoped means?   It is blatantly clear that the question describes what it wants and the answer gives what is asked for.   This is exactly what I wanted to know.   There is an existence proof right in front of you that the question's scope is fine.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I've lost the will to argue with you. I'm happy that you're happy.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The joint winners in terms of actual appearances are **Scotty** (7+0/10):

- TOS
- TAS
- TNG ("Relics")
- DS9 ("Trials and Tribble-ations")
- TOS films
- TNG films (*Generations*)
- Reboot films

...and **Spock** (7+0/10):

- TOS
- TAS
- TNG ("Unification")
- DS9 ("Trials and Tribble-ations")
- TOS films
- Reboot films
- Discovery (multiple season 2 episodes)

(Kirk does not appear in TNG. McCoy does not appear in the TNG films. Sarek does not appear in any of the TNG-era films or spinoffs. I could find nobody else who appears in more than five of your categories.)

---

Unsurprisingly, the winner in terms of bare mentions is almost certainly **Kirk** (6+3/10):

Appears in:

- TOS
- TAS
- TOS films
- TNG films (*Generations*)
- DS9 ("Trials and Tribble-ations")
- Reboot films

Mentioned in:

- TNG ("The Naked Now" referencing "The Naked Time")
- Voyager (Icheb does an assignment on him in "Q2")
- Enterprise (A blink-and-you'll-miss-it mention in "These Are The Voyages" to the scanners on his ship — also, the voiceover at the end of the episode includes Shatner's voice)

So, everything except Discovery, depending on how you count the mentions.

---

Honorable mentions:

**Sarek** (6+1/10)

Appears in:

- TOS ("Journey to Babel")
- TAS ("Yesteryear")
- TNG ("Sarek", "Unification")
- Discovery (recurring)
- TOS films (all but the first two)
- Reboot films (the first one)

Mentioned in:

- DS9 (Garak misattributes a quote to him in "Profit and Loss")

**Cochrane** (3+3/10)

Appears in:

- TOS ("Metamorphosis")
- TNG films (*First Contact*)
- Enterprise ("Broken Bow", in a recording; Mirror Cochrane appears in the opening to "In a Mirror, Darkly")

Mentioned in:

- TNG ("New Ground" — Geordi compares the test they're going to watch to Cochrane's first warp drive test)
- Voyager (referenced as a famous test pilot in "Threshold"; appears as a trivia question in "Year of Hell"; etc.)
- Discovery (Lorca calls him a famous pioneer along with the Wright Brothers and Elon Musk)

Comment: Minor point: Chekov should have  score of 6? As well, (taken from Koenig's wiki page) "Koenig reprised the role of Chekov for the fan web series Star Trek: New Voyages, "To Serve All My Days", and the independent Sky Conway/Tim Russ film Star Trek: Of Gods and Men, both in 2006, and Star Trek: Renegades, in 2015. According to the teaser for Renegades episodes 2 and 3, this will be the last time Koenig plays the role of Chekov"

Comment: @jim In that case, Uhura should get the same score. You don't see many productions these day that feature Chekov without Uhura by his side.

Comment: @jim - those aren't canon though

Comment: @MrLister Cheers

Comment: Excellent work!   I don't get why people always want to quibble over what is in or what is out, and complain about scoping, when the best and most interesting answer is to simply explain the considerations.

Comment: Doesn't Sulu also tie with Sarek since he showed up in Tuvok's crazy mind-meld that one time on Voyager? Wait no Sarek also showed up in the first Kelvin-verse film.

Comment: @ThePopMachine We're Trek fans. Quibbling over minutiae is what we do.

Comment: Cochrane was also in the mirror universe first episode in Enterprise, he shoots the Vulcans who come to meet him.

Comment: You may soon have to update this answer: https://io9.gizmodo.com/a-young-spock-will-appear-in-star-trek-discovery-seaso-1825277277

Answer (score 2):

Number of appearance wise, it would have to be Worf right? He was in all but 4 episodes of TNG, all but 8 episodes of DS9 after season 4, and all 4 TNG films, for a total of 274 appearances.

Comment: Except that we are not counting appearances as a total, but any appearance in a series. But this is good research, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

Riker appears in:

- TNG
- TNG films
- DS9 ("Defiant" arguably)
- VOY ("Death Wish")
- ENT ("These Are the Voyages...")